# How to perfectly simulate typewriter style?

Tags: pdftex, typewriter

I want to simulate typewriter style typesetted math articles. There are a few major requirements:

- All characters in all environments be tt style and of the same size and width (including super and sub scripts in math mode). In math mode, sub and super scripts should be one character higher than the base. All emphasizing should be replaced by underline.
- Spacing between all kinds of lines, including spacing between lists or figures and texts, should be always integral multiples of character height. The multiple can vary according to the height of inline equations (e.g., when too many levels of superscripts, should leave space for superscripts to avoid overlapping).
- All spaces being the same width as characters, no adjustments to fit line breaking. If a word cannot fit in one line, leave it to the next line.

To conclude, all elements should be arranged as if the page is separated into "grids", each grid of the size of a tt character. All elements should be placed exactly fitting one or multiple grids in both vertical and horizontal directions, there is no "half" space or something like that. Is it possible to fulfill these requirements in LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome! A few questions: (1) what have you tried? You might get lucky, but your question is more likely to get closed because it isn't focused on a specific issue. It is just a do-this-big-complicated-thing-for-me. (2) I assume all mathematical symbols not available on a typewriter should appear as spaces so you can write them in afterwards. Is that correct? That is, most operators, all accents, arrows, most delimiters, Greek (unless it is a Greek typewriter and Latin should be omitted?). (3) Why do this at all? (4) Why do it in LaTeX of all things?

Comment: You may want to check the `typewriter` package; https://www.ctan.org/pkg/typewriter